# Why doesn't line-height work in this case?

Tags: html, css

See my code below:
(see my codepen: https://codepen.io/Chiz/pen/GRQrrLb)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

aside {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 50px 40px;
  width: 230px;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.related-author {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.related {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.post-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
}

.post-box div {
  margin-top: -7px;
}

.post-box a {
  line-height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <ul class="related">
    <li class="post-box">
      <div>
        <a href="#">How to Learn Web Development</a>
        <p class="related-author">By Jonas Schmedtmann</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="post-box">
      <div>
        <a href="#">The Unknown Powers of CSS</a>
        <p class="related-author">By Jim Dillon</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="post-box">

      <div>
        <a href="#">Why JavaScript is Awesome</a>
        <p class="related-author">By Matilda</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

In the CSS panel, at the very bottom, I set the line-height to 0px to the links in blue, so logically speaking, the lines in blue should all collapse onto themselves in 1 line.

But why doesn't it work?

Comment: Because your links are inline elements, add `display: inline-block` or `block`.

Comment: It does work. try `line-height: 150px`

Answer (score 1):

It does work but there is another `line-height` that you need to consider, the one of its parent.

Here is a simplified example to better understand:

```css
div {
  outline:1px solid;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="">some text</a>
</div>

<div >
  <a href="" style="line-height:0">some text</a>
</div>

<div style="line-height:0;">
  <a href="">some text</a>
</div>

<div style="line-height:0;">
  <a href="" style="line-height:0">some text</a>
</div>
```

Setting the `line-height` to only the parent is enough because the child will inherit it but setting the `line-height` to only the child is not enough because the parent will have the default `line-height` that will set the height of the line box

---

In your case you need to do the following:

```
.post-box > div {
  line-height: 0; /* set it on the parent */
}
.post-box > div p {
  line-height: initial; /* don't let the p inherit the line-height */
}
```

full code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

aside {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 50px 40px;
  width: 230px;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.related-author {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.related {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.post-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
}
.post-box div {
  margin-top: -7px;
}

.post-box > div {
  line-height: 0; /* set it on the parent */
}
.post-box > div p {
  line-height: initial; /* don't let the p inherit the line-height */
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <ul class="related">
    <li class="post-box">
      <div>
        <a href="#">How to Learn Web Development</a>
        <p class="related-author">By Jonas Schmedtmann</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="post-box">
      <div>
        <a href="#">The Unknown Powers of CSS</a>
        <p class="related-author">By Jim Dillon</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="post-box">

      <div>
        <a href="#">Why JavaScript is Awesome</a>
        <p class="related-author">By Matilda</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: Well Explained...

Comment: But it doesn't work?  If you run the final code snippet it's not collapsing the links?

Comment: @RichN it does, add display:none to the links to notice that the height of the div won't change. The link no more affect the height and the layout, it's overflowing the line box